# VIM Delete in - multiple lines

Tags: vim

Is there any way I can do something like `di>` on multiple lines

So

```
<Hello>{caret position here}
    <World>
        <Something />
    </World>
</Hello>
```

turns to:

```
<Hello></Hello>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the `it` or "inner tag" text-object

```
dit
```

For more help see `:h it` & `:h at`

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the solution must be `2dit` if you are inside the second tag, otherwise `dit`.